Was this old drywall mud that chipped off the ceiling?
We had a roof leak a while back which I noticed when the ceiling paint started to bulge and bubble downward. I immediately pinpricked it and the water came out of the hole that I made.
Fast forward to today, when I'm finally getting around to repairing the bubble appearance in the ceiling. I basically chipped away the paint on the ceiling that was part of the bubble and that would move when you'd press against it.
When I did so, it looked like this:

Note two things here. First, the thickness of what I chipped off seems quite clearly thicker than just paint. Secondly, you can see the tape from the drywall work before. Am I correct to interpret this situation in that the roof leak went through the drywall (which is still intact it seems as it's behind the tape) and that the stuff I scraped off was the old paint + the old mud which was used to finish?
Just want to make sure I understand what's going on here. I thought maybe I'd see just some drywall and maybe even be chipping through drywall paper. I didn't expect to see "clean" drywall tape.
Started applying mud to try to fix this. Hopefully a couple coats will work and I won't need to replace the drywall entirely.


Your deduction is correct.

Thanks for the confirmation.

Some friendly advice. Do yourself a favor and invest in a wide 12 inch drywall knife.   Your mud repair will be much better if you use a wide knife and apply the mud like a window washer with a squeegee rather than a baker frosting a cake with a butterknife.

Yeah, I actually have 10" knife I did some of this with. Problem was that the middle part of the patch was so much lower than the edges and the drywall knife didn't span to the non-patched space so the knife was dipping down in the middle. I don't think a 12" would have been wide enough either. As the middle loses some of its recess, I hope that the passes will become much more smooth.
